# Is there a way to check if both data sets are the same( Pentaho & OracleDB)

Tags: sql, etl, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am using Pentaho (Spoon PDI), I have created input and output transformations. When running the sql in OracleDB I get back all the rows and data Pentaho I can generate a preview of the data set(generally 1000 rows).

Is there a tool where I can verify if all the returned values are the same between the two ? I have tried returning rows in each data set as a start but it seems like an innefficent way to go about this. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: PDI allows you to log transformation and step metadata (like numbers of rows processed, duration) into files or database tables. You could then compare the expected number of rows from your oracle db to the processed number of rows in your log table.

Comment: Your question is not clear, if you are confused why it is only showing 1000 rows then let me tell you, you can change the preview limit as per your requirement. secondly we have merge rows diff step which compares and gives the result with flag matching or new row

Comment: Do you want to verify the sql input result with the pentaho output. Please elaborate